# Program to get public link from image automatically

Tags: images, raspberry-pi

I need a program that can get a public link for a local image automatically. (using any service, so long as there is a link for it) So it will need to upload the image somewhere and return a link for me to use. Preferably it also needs to work with Raspberry Pi, but that might be pushing it. (it also needs to be free) Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Do the usual image hosting sites like Imgur maybe have such tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Python](http://www.python.org) + [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/python) or any other sharing service:

- Work on anything, *(just about),* including Raspberry-Pi.
- Free
- The only down side is that you need to do some work first.

Just follow the quick start instructions and take a look at the demos & APIs to find out how to upload a file, share it & get the link to share it with.

Answer (score 0):

[Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) offers that after you put a copy inside your Dropbox folder:

[image]

My UI is in German, but it basically says "Share a dropbox link" which you can then give to someone.